# Is it possible to use Lita to make an app and release to App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am a beginner of making an iPhone app.
I would like to ask if it is possible to use Lita as a database and make an iOS app?
I would like to release the app to an Apple Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lita is not a database, it is just a SQLite manager.

You can use SQLite in your iOS without problems, SQLite is available in the iOS SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. So, if I would like to make a database, what should I do? Sorry it this is a silly question.

Comment: Just create one? Sorry but without any context or anything your answer can be answered. Also you should really try thing before post questions. I think you should start by learning to program.